# how to bind v-model to child component that contains input

Tags: javascript, vue.js, babeljs

I have some components that look like this.

```
<template>
  <q-layout>
    <v-input v-model="something" />
  </q-layout>
</template>

<script>
import { QLayout } from 'quasar'
import { Input } from 'vedana'

export default {
  name: 'index',
  components: {
    QLayout,
    Input
  },
  data () {
    return {
      something: ''
    }
  }
}
```

this v-input component looks like this:

```
<template>
    <input
        :type="type ? type : 'text'"
        class="v-input"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['type'],
    name: 'v-input'
}
</script>
```

When I enter data into the input `something` does not bind to whatever is in the value of the input that is inside of v-input.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You are importing `Input` but using `v-input` component ... am I missing something?

Comment: I set the name property on the component to v-input

Comment: The `<input>` doesn't have a `value` or `v-model` binding, for starters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To enable the use of [`v-model` the inner component must take a `value` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Customizing-Component-v-model).

Bind the `value` to the inner `<input>` using `:value`, not `v-model` (this would mutate the prop coming from the parent). And when the inner `<input>` is edited, emit an `input` event for the parent, to update its value (`input` event will update the variable the parent has on `v-model`).

Also, if you have a default value for the `type` prop, declare it in `props`, not in the template.

Here's how your code should be

```
<template>
    <input
        :type="type"
        :value="value"
        @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
        class="v-input" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: {
      type: {default() { return 'text'; }},
      value: {}                              // you can also add more restrictions here
    },
    name: 'v-input'
}
</script>
```

Info about what `props` can have: [Components / Passing data With Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props).

Demo below.

```js
Vue.component('v-input', {
  template: '#v-input-template',
  props: {
    type: {default() { return 'text'; }},
    value: {}                              // you can also add more restrictions here
  },
  name: 'v-input'
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    something: "I'm something"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <p>Parent something: {{ something }}</p>
  <hr>
  Child: <v-input v-model="something" />
</div>

<template id="v-input-template">
   <input
      :type="type"
      :value="value"
      @input="$emit('input', $event.target.value)"
      class="v-input" />
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing something similar to this, but I didn't pass the value down as a prop. I see why you did it that way and I may change it in the future, but I would like to keep it as minimal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#sync-Modifier

```
<template>
  <q-layout>
    <v-input :value.sync="something" />
  </q-layout>
</template>

<template>
    <input
    :type="type ? type : 'text'"
    v-model="inputVal"
    class="v-input"/>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    props: ['type', 'value'],
    name: 'v-input',
    data:function(){
        return {
            inputVal: ''
        };
    },
    watch:{
        value: function(newValue){
            this.$emit('update:value', newValue)
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

You need to pass your value to the input component using the `.sync` modifier so the changes will sync back to the parent.

Comment: You're modifying a prop by using `v-model` on it.

Comment: @RoyJ coming from vue 1 I had not realized the `.sync` modifier functionality had changed, thank you.